# Limiting the number of rows returned by a BiqQuery user defined function

Tags: google-bigquery

According to Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#limit-clause-and-offset-clause), the `limit` and `offset` clauses in a query can only accept "literal or parameter values."

I figured the function below would be legal, since the I'm using the parameter `cnt` in the limit clause.

```
  retrieveLimitedRows(cnt int64) AS ((SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT cnt));
```

Alas. BigQuery tells me `Syntax error: Unexpected identifier "cnt" at [3:63]`. If `cnt` isn't a parameter here, then what is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If cnt isn't a parameter here, then what is?

In that documentation, term parameter is reference to parameters in [Parameterized Queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) and not to argument in temp or permanent UDF/function!